# Disable a button when an event occure in main activity

Tags: android

I have two activities named Main activity and Second Activity. Main activity has an event handler. I need to disable a button in second activity when an event occurs.

Main activity

```
public void myEventListener(int eventID){

  switch (eventID) {
  case : 0
   // disable button of second activity here
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: does main activity always comes before second activity?

Comment: yes. second activity comes only after main activity.

Comment: check this answer and let me know if it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221060/7360848

Comment: You can use the global variable from the file "AppConstants" and use that to set the button enable or disable, by changing the variable status true/false when your event is inprogress/done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy one.

1. Use `SharedPreference` of changing **data**(boolean maybe) in `MainAcitivity`
2. Use `SharedPreference.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `SecondActivity` for listening to that specific **data** and changing button state at runtime in.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public void myEventListener(int eventID){

    switch (eventID) {
        case  0:
            editor = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("event",true);

        break;
    }
}

}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if(key.equals("event") && sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,false))
    {
        //add your code to disable your button or any action you want

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I edited my code, this was just a place holder, meaning to be replaced by your own custom action

Comment: onSharedPreferenceChanged is not occuring.

Comment: i used similar approach many times, it must work, check your implantation

Answer (score 0):

In you First Activity make Boolean static variable.

**Example:**

**FirstActivity**

*create a Boolean static global variable*

```
public static Boolean clicked = false;
```

**onFirstActivity if Event occurs.**

event occurred => `clicked = true;` otherwise it is false

**SecondActivity**

in second activity get the value to static boolean from FirstActivity

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if (FirstActivity.clicked){
                     //Do Nothing
              }else{
                     //Perform action
              }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't use intent because event occure only after the second activity started.

Comment: but how i know the event is occured or not in second activity?

Comment: when button is clicked you can fetch the static Boolean variable of FirstActivity. See my code,,

Comment: but i need it without clicking a button . I mean When the event occure it automatically disable the button

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to disable a button. Follow the below steps to achieve your problem.

1. Define a global boolean value as "false"
2. In onClickEvent override, the boolean value as "true".

Then check with the boolean value as follows

```
private boolean isClicked = false;

if(isClicked){
   button.disabled(true);
} else {
   button.disabled(false);
}
```

Please let me know if you have any issues while applying.

Comment: i have different activites need to disable button of second activity when an event occure in first activity.

Comment: @MuraleedharanpillaiK You can simply pass the boolean value as true in Intent using putExtra. Then using a getIntent method in onCreate of the SecondActivity, you can pick the boolean value and place the if condition to disable and enable the button. You don't need to use any broadCastReceivers or hard methods to accomplish your requirement. If you find any difficulties, please let me know

Comment: can i pass value with putExtra in the middle of second activity is running. I know the answer is no.

Comment: I think you are confusing, please try to follow the below steps.


1. Create intent to move from Activity A to Activity B and in this intent pass the boolean value as true.

2. In second Activity B using getIntent method fetch the boolean value using the same key as you have been used in the intent in Activity A.

syn: In second Activity B

Intent intent = getIntent();
Boolean b = intent.getBooleanExtra("Key");

Answer (score 0):

first make reference of second activity and set button visibility GONE or INVISIBLE It's Work

```
SeconActivity sa;      //reference of second activity
public void myEventListener(int eventID){
switch (eventID) {
case : 0
sa.btnofsecondactivity.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
break;
}
}
```

Comment: sorry it is not good idea to create an object of an activity having life cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [LocalBroadCastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager).

in MainActivity wherever you want to trigger the method

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("event-occured"));
```

in SecondActivity register the LocalBroadcastManager and receive it.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver mainActivityReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mainActivityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do whatever you want to do

            Log.d("TAG", "broadcast received");
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mainActivityReceiver, new IntentFilter("main-activity-initialized"));
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mainActivityReceiver);
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the listener in SecondActivity's onDestroy method. Taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager/8875292#8875292).

Comment: because mListner is not initialized

Comment: Updated the answer with localBroadcastManager. Have a look. Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: if its worked for you then please accept it as answer,